# mediaElementjs: how to get instance of the player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, mediaelement

I'm stuck with a little problem with MediaElement.js player.

To get the instance of the player, I do this (works with html5 compatible browser):

```
    // Get player
this.playerId = $('div#shotlist-player video').attr('id');
this.player = window[this.playerId];
```

But it's not working as soon as it fallback in flash. In fact, it's not working because I'm not calling an instance of MediaElement itself. But I don't see how I can call it.

The player is created with

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer({....});
```

How can I get the mediaelement object?

------------EDIT----------------

Ok I finally found how to make it works:

```
    // Get player
mePlayer = $('div#shotlist-player video.video-js')[0];
this.player = new MediaElementPlayer(mePlayer);
```

Now I can user mediaElement instance correctly.

Comment: You can get the player in a much nicer way: `this.player = $('div#shotlist-player video')[0];` - actually, I think window[id] only works in IE (and there it's one of the most stupid and annoying misfeatures ever)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but actually, I'm still not selecting mediaelement instance, but the <video> player directly, which is not what I need (I need to be able to control the flash player too).

Answer (score 2):

This post is a lot of speculation, but may be correct. Docs are lacking (;

The answer by [sidonaldson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9101099/141881) is perfectly acceptable if you wish to create a new MediaElement instance and get a handle on it. If there's one already present, it seems to try to reinitialize another instance on that element and freaks out.

I am pretty sure mediaelement.js augments the builtin HTML5 controls by providing a JavaScript API to manipulate Flash/Silverlight players via those elements. I may be wrong, but other advice I've seen on this issue in multiple places is to do something like:

```
$playButton.click(function() {
    $('video, audio').each(function() {
        $(this)[0].player.play();
    });
});
```

To create a play button as an external DOM element which will fire off all players on the page. This indicates to me that the implementation is something like I've described.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var player = $('video').mediaelementplayer({                
    success: function (me) {
         me.play();
    }
});
// then you can use player.id to return the id
// or player.play();
```